# AndroidBitmap_lockPixels() and SWIG

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, swig

In my project Java and C++ interactions are made with SWIG. The problem is that I need to use function [`AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(JNIEnv *env, jobject jbitmap, void **addrPtr)`](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/bitmap#group___bitmap_1ga2908d42fa4db286c34b7f8c11f29206f), whic requires `JNIEnv *env`. Is it possible to write a function of C++ structure/class that will accept `Bitmap` (from Java, Android) as parameter and call `AndroidBitmap_lockPixels()` with it, in SWIG?

Comment: Write a small helper function that returns `void *` that you can cast to a Java `long`? See [Documentation](https://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/Java.html#Java_using_own_jni_functions)

Comment: @Botje Disarming question. Why do i need `long`?

Comment: That is the only Java primitive capable of holding a pointer across all environments. You could try it with `lockPixels` directly but I have no idea how it will handle the `void**` argument.

Comment: Thats not an issue. I need `JNIENV*` to call function, but I have on idea how to get it

Comment: The `%native` annotation whose documentation I linked shows how you can register custom-made JNI functions with SWIG. That function will be called with the proper JNIEnv.

Comment: Seen that. But I don't know how to appy it in my case. In provided example class is in Java, and function is declared in C++. Mine class in completely in C++. And it's not clear where to write function body

Comment: Oh. if it is completely in C++ you can just the invocation API.